# C# Convert Hex String Array to Byte Array

Tags: c#, arrays, hex

I have a `String[]` of **hex** values `"10" "0F" "3E" "42"` stored.

I found this method to convert to a `Byte[]`

```
    public static byte[] ToByteArray(String HexString)
    {
        int NumberChars = HexString.Length;
        byte[] bytes = new byte[NumberChars / 2];
        for (int i = 0; i < NumberChars; i += 2)
        {
            bytes[i / 2] = Convert.ToByte(HexString.Substring(i, 2), 16);
        }
        return bytes;
    }
```

However this converts the values to the hex equivalent. But the values are already in the **hex** equivalent!

For example this makes `"10" "0F" "3E" "42"` into `"16" "15" "62" "66"`.

I want it to directly copy the values as they are already the correct hex value.

**Edit:**

Basically...

I want a **byte array** with the literal characters in the `String[]` So say the second value in `String[]` is `0F`. I want the first byte in `Byte[]` to be `0F` and not 16

Any ideas?

**Edit2**

Let me clarify. I don't want to convert my `String[]` values into **Hexadecimal**, as they are already **Hexadecimal**. I want to directly copy them to a Byte[]

The problem is my string of values `"10" "0F" "3E" 42"` already has the hexadecimal value I want. I want the byte array to contain those exact values and not convert them, they are already **hexadecimal** form.

Comment: `byte[] result hexValues.Select(value => Convert.ToByte(value, 16)).ToArray();`

Comment: What is your desired output? I think you are confused because you are viewing the values as base 10.

Comment: I want a byte array with the literal characters in the String[]

So say the second value in String[] is 0F. I want the first in Byte[] to be 0F and not 16.

Comment: What is `HexString`s value?

Comment: `10` hexadecimal is `16` decimal. If you want hexadecimal output, use formatting: `Console.Write($"{15:x2}");` will print out `0f` (note `x2` format string - at least `2` hexadecimal)

Comment: I understand 10 hexadecimal is 16. 

I don't want my string[] values to convert to hexadecimal. They are already hexadecimal. 

I want to directly copy from my values from string[] into byte[] without converting to hex, because they are already the hex values I want.

Comment: `byte` doesn't have any format (decimal, hexadecimal, binary etc.) inside it. `byte b = 0x0f;` is neither hexadecimal nor decimal, it's just a value. It can be *represented* as decimal: `b.ToString()` or hexadecimal `b.ToString("x2")`

Comment: You're probably looking for something like `byte b = byte.Parse("5F", System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to *convert* (or *parse*) `string` in order to get `byte` since `string` and `byte` are *different types*:

```
// 10 == 10d 
byte b = Convert.ToByte("10");     // if "10" is a decimal representation
// 16 == 0x10
byte b = Convert.ToByte("10", 16); // if "10" is a hexadecimal representation
```

If you want to process an *array*, you can try a simple *Linq*:

```
using System.Linq;

...

string[] hexValues = new string[] {
  "10", "0F", "3E", "42"};

byte[] result = hexValues
  .Select(value => Convert.ToByte(value, 16))
  .ToArray();
```

If you want to print out `result` as *hexadecimal*, use formatting (`"X2"` format string - at least `2` *hexadecimal* digits, use *captital* letters):

```
// 10, 0F, 3E, 42
Console.Write(string.Join(", ", result.Select(b => b.ToString("X2"))));
```

Compare with *same* array but in a *different format* (`"d2"` - at least `2` *decimal* digits)

```
// 16, 15, 62, 66 
Console.Write(string.Join(", ", result.Select(b => b.ToString("d2"))));
```

If no format provided, .Net uses default one and represents `byte` in decimal:

```
// 16, 15, 62, 66 
Console.Write(string.Join(", ", result));
```

Answer (score 0):

You're really confusing *representation* and *numbers* here.

A string like `"0F"` can be seen as a representation of a number in base 16, that is, in decimal representation, *16*.

Which is the exact same thing as representing *16* as *F* or *0F* or *XVI* or 
*IIIIIIIIIIIIIIII* or whatever other representation you choose.

The string `"0F"` actually looks in memory like this

Hexadecimal representation:

```
0x30 0x46 0x00
```

Decimal representation:

```
48 70 0
```

Binary representation:

```
0b00110000 0b01000110 0b00000000
```

Comment: The problem with my understanding is that my string - "10" "0F" "3E" "42"

Really is 0x10, 0x0F, 0x3E, 0x42. I didnt want any conversion, it was already Hex. My confusion came because the byte array list was using the decimal value (16 for 0x10) for example and I didn't realize that bytes can be stored as decimal. I was expecting 0x10 in the byte array and not 16.

Answer (score 0):

`Byte` is simply a `data type` which is infact a subset of an `integer`.

`Byte` takes `interger` values ranging from `-2^7(-128) to 2^7-1$(127)`

Calling `Convert.ToByte(string, 16)` simply converts your `string` to an equivalent `hex value` and then to an equivalent value in `byte`.

Note the `byte data type` is always an `integer data` but used in place of an integer just to save space in memory. As referenced above the byte datatype takes values from `-128 to 127` thereby saving you more space in memory than the `integer data type` would.

Please Note that you are likely to run into an error if the `hexadecimal` value you wish to convert to `byte` is less than `-128` or greater than `127`

The link below shows an instance of this error when I try converting a `string` whose value when converted to `hexadecimal` is greater than `127`.

[Error when converting to Byte](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e1R6r.png)

You get an error whenever you do this.

I hope my answer and Dmitry Bychenko's sheds more light into your problem.
Please feel free to comment if it doesnt.